# Find second customer visit based on custom conditions in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a customer visit table in postgre sql with the following fields `customer_id`, `visit_date`, `purchase_amount`. For each unique customer, I want to find their first and second visit.

I find their first treatment by

```
min(d.visit_date) OVER (PARTITION BY d.customer_id) as index_visit_date
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to find the second treatment because I want to define the second visit as a visit at least 60 days after the index_visit_date.

So if a customer has the following visit history:

```
 id|visit_date|purchase_amount
 1 | 10-19-19 |1000
 1 | 10-24-19 |100
 1 | 12-15-19 |1000
```

The index_visit_date = 10-19-19 and the second_treatment = 12-15-19

I am not sure how to calculate the difference in time from index_visit_date and then select the next visit a minimum of 60 days after as the second treatment.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a lateral join:

```
select vfirst.*, vnext.*
from (select distinct on (id) v.*
      from visits v
      order by id, visit_date
     ) vfirst left join lateral
     (select vnext.*
      from visits vnext
      where vnext.id = vfirst.id and
            vnext.visit_date >= vfirst.visit_date + interval '60 day'
      order by vnext.visit_date
      limit 1
     ) vnext
     on true;
```

Actually, if you just want the date, there are simpler methods, such as:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by visit_date) as seqnum,
             min(visit_date) over (partition by id
                                   order by visit_date
                                   range between '60 day' following and unbounded following
                                  ) as next_visit_date
      from visits v
     ) v
where seqnum = 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=23b36b3d2844bd48e35757dbf7d3c4eb) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hmm neither solution is working for me. The first method is throwing the error that distinct on is not supported. The second method is throwing a syntax error for the 60 days. I am running this in redshift postgre if that helps

Comment: @dsmess . . . They work fine.  Your sample data has no instance with a visit more than 60 days after the first visit.